# Running .Net Core web application in Windows subsystem for linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, web-deployment, windows-subsystem-for-linux

We are planning to use Azure Linux  app service for deploying our .net core ERP web application.
All our developers are currently having windows machines. We would like to have a Linux distribution for each of them to run and test the application. We are considering Windows Subsystem for Linux.  Do we have to install Visual Studio separately there in WSL and build the application ?  OR is there any way just to get the release files specific to Linux from VS in Windows and somehow deploy/run using WSL?

Comment: *"What would be the ideal solution?"* -- Just a heads-up that you might want to reword that, since it brushes up against the "opinion-based" [off-topic rule](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (for most Stack sites).  Also, it's possible that you'll get downvotes (or closed) for the lack of focus - There are multiple questions there, so there may be multiple answers which cover it (but only one can be accepted).  For this type of "discussion" style question, I'd personally recommend the WSL subreddit [/r/ubuntubashonwindows](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/).

Comment: Also a separate heads-up that the ACM is hosting a session tomorrow (August 11) with Scott Hanselman which may be of interest to you on this topic.  Assuming you have at least one developer there who is an ACM member, have them register you for the event or download the recording after.  Excerpt:  *Can you really use Windows to develop Linux apps? How real is WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and how close is it to reality? Join Scott Hanselman as he walks you through the state of the art of Linux on Windows. What's possible, what's not, what about the Windows Terminal and Docker?*